# Why are there normal answers in community wiki questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

In some community wiki questions I saw some of the answers are also community wiki, but some of them remain normal answers with the answerer's avatar being displayed like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414911/995714). Why is that?

Comment: Got a link to an example?

Comment: @AnnaLear http://stackoverflow.com/q/1414911/995714

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : Kindly include this link in the question itself

Answer (score 3):

*In general*, I'd likely chalk it up to historical differences between how CW used to work and how it works now. Or a bug. :)

*In [this specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414911)*, my best guess (without digging too deeply) is that the author of the accepted answer made their answer CW when they posted it.

As an aside, I removed CW from that question and the accepted answer, since it makes little sense for either to be a wiki.

Comment: when I posted an answer there I didn't select the CW box, neither did I know about its existence, but my answer was still made CW